# How to avoid MySQL composite primary key permutations?

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

```sql
CREATE TABLE Friends_Relations(
    buddy_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    mate_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (buddy_id, mate_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (buddy_id) REFERENCES Users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (mate_id) REFERENCES Users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

There's this mutual friendship relation where (friend_A, friend_B) is the same as (friend_B, friend_A).

I've tried adding a unique key, but it was to no avail:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Friends_Relation ADD UNIQUE KEY (mate_id, buddy_id);
```

Is there a way to avoid these permutations ?

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to add the reverse relationship using a trigger.  Having both directions is often helpful for querying.

Comment: ...with a flag to identify the true relationship (it matters sometimes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
create table friends_relations (
  buddy_id varchar(255) not null,
  mate_id varchar(255) not null,
  constraint uq1 unique (
    (least(buddy_id, mate_id)), (greatest(buddy_id, mate_id))
  ),
  primary key (buddy_id, mate_id)
);
```

Then if it won't accept symmetric rows:

```
insert into friends_relations (buddy_id, mate_id) values (456, 123);
insert into friends_relations (buddy_id, mate_id) values (123, 456); -- fails
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f5b4069c668945b3fa2aa1e12379f56).

There's also another *trick*. What you can alternatively do is to enforce `buddy_id < mate_id`. This, however, will restrict the way you insert data. For example you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE Friends_Relations (
    buddy_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    mate_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (buddy_id, mate_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (buddy_id) REFERENCES Users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (mate_id) REFERENCES Users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    constraint ck1 CHECK (buddy_id < mate_id) -- added constraint
);
```

Then, when you insert:

```
insert into Friends_Relations (buddy_id, mate_id) values (123, 456); -- succeeds

insert into Friends_Relations (buddy_id, mate_id) values (456, 123); -- fails
```

Comment: A check constraint is an elegant solution (it also enforces some kind of data integrity by forcing one value to be smaller than the other one). It should just be noted that it is only available in very recent versions of MySQL (8.0.13 if I remember correctly). In earlier versions, check constraints are parsed without errors, but ignored (which is rather tricky).

Comment: close - [8.0.16](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)

Answer (score 1):

[from this dba exchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273479/how-can-i-enforce-that-my-composite-key-columns-do-not-equal-one-another-in-mysq/273480#27348)

```
ALTER TABLE Friends_Relation ADD UNIQUE KEY 
((least(buddy_id,mate_id)), (greatest(buddy_id,mate_id)))
```

This allows the pair in either order, but still only once.